# Query or procedure or logic that I could use to only get new entries from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im quite new to SQL and trying to find a solution for this.

I have a database with multiple tables on it and then I use a sqlcmd to export all the entries for each table onto a csv file (1 csv file for each table)

Afterward what i do with the excel file is put it into a blob container on Azure.

How would i be able to do it so that whenever there is a new entry or an update on the table it would then create an excel file and then just input the new entries on it? without the old entries.

I am only using SQL Server Express and cant use SQL Server Standard.

code below would export all entries on the table.

sqlcmd -s "servername" -d "databasename" -u username -P password -Q "select * from dbo.tbl_check" -o "C:\Test\dbo_tbl_check.csv" -W -w 1024 -s","

For example if i had run the code when the table still has entries like this.

[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlXS2.png)

it would then show up all the result on a csv file

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lebI8.png)

and then the database gets updated again on march6

[picture3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJqJT.png)

i was hoping that the excel file it would recreate would then just have this entry.

[picture4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlckT.png)

Comment: You need to record the changes. There are many ways to do this. One is to add a datetime field to the table and populate it when data changes. Then you can use that. The other is to turn on SQL Server CDC and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table to remember the last exported id:

```
Create Table IncrementalExportMem
(
TableName NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
LastId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_IncrementalExportMem_LastId DEFAULT(0),
CONSTRAINT PK_IncrementalExportMem PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TableName)
)
```

Create procedure for export table:

```
CREATE Procedure spIncrementalExport
@TableName NVARCHAR(200),
@IdField NVARCHAR(200),
@SelectColumns NVARCHAR(max)='*'
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @LastID INT
DECLARE @NextLastId INT

    SELECT @LastID FROM IncrementalExportMem WHERE Tablename=@TableName

IF @LastID IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO IncrementalExportMem(tableName) VALUES(@TableName)
    SET @LastID=0
END

SET @SQL='SELECT @NextLastId=MAX('+ @IdField +') FROM '+@TableName
exec sp_executesql @SQL,N'@NextLastId INT OUTPUT',@NextLastId OUTPUT

SET @NextLastId= ISNULL(@NextLastId,0)


SET @SQL=CONCAT('SELECT ',@SelectColumns,' FROM ',@TableName,' WHERE ',@IdField,'>',@LastID,' AND ',@IdField,'<=',@NextLastId)
exec sp_executesql @SQL

UPDATE IncrementalExportMem SET LastId=@NextLastId WHERE Tablename=@TableName

END
```

in your script use command:

```
sqlcmd -s "servername" -d "databasename" -u username -P password -Q "exec spIncrementalExport 'your_table','id_in_table'" -o "C:\Test\dbo_tbl_check.csv" -W -w 1024 -s","
```